# In Laravel only one of two joins work when the second parameter is a function with LIKE

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one search term `$term`.

I have 3 tables.

1st is `vehicles` 
and has `id` (int, autoincr., unique), `vehicle_id` (int) - which can be identical, `vehicle_type` (int) - can be 1 or 2 - 1 denotes car and 2 is for motorcycle. Example, how it could look like:

```
----------------------------------
| id | vehicle_id | vehicle_type |
|--------------------------------|
| 1  | 546        | 1            |
----------------------------------
| 2  | 257        | 1            |
----------------------------------
| 3  | 546        | 2            |
----------------------------------
| 4  | 368        | 1            |
----------------------------------
```

2nd is `cars`
and has `id` (int, autoincr., unique), `title` - (varchar), Example:

```
-------------------
| id | title      | 
|------------------
|544  | Abbycar   | 
-------------------
|545  | Batmobil  | 
-------------------
|546 | WackyWheel | 
-------------------
|547  | Ferrari   | 
-------------------
```

3nd is `motorcycles`
and has `id` (int, autoincr., unique), `title` - (varchar), Example:

```
-------------------
| id | title      | 
|------------------
|544 | Abbycycle  | 
-------------------
|545 | Batcycle   | 
-------------------
|546 | WackyBike  | 
-------------------
|547 | Motorrari  | 
-------------------
```

Now, I want to use the 1st table's **vehicle_id** (vehicle.vehicle_id) and join it with the 2nd table's **id** (cars.id) but only under the condition that the **vehicle_type** is 1 (car). And at the same time the car's title should contain the **$term** using LIKE.

And at the same time I want to join 1st table's **vehicle_id** (vehicle.vehicle_id) with the 3rd table's **id** (motorcycles.id) but only under the condition that the **vehicle_type** is 2 (motorcycle). And at the same time the motorcycle's title should contain the **$term** using LIKE.

So far, I have this code:

```
$result = DB::table('vehicles')->join('cars', function($join) use($term)
                                {
                                    $join->on('vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'cars.id') 
                                         ->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', '1')
                                         ->where('cars.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
                                })
                               ->join('motorcycles', function($join2) use($term)
                                {
                                    $join2->on('vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'motorcycles.id')
                                         ->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', '2')
                                         ->where('motorcycles.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
                               })
                               ->get();
```

The problem is that when I have a car and a motorcycle that have the same name and teh $term contains part of it, only the car is catched. If I comment the cars join part the motorcyle is shown, but I want both. How to do that?

Why is the second join being ignored?

Because this works:

```
$result = DB::table('vehicles')->join('cars', function($join) use($term)
                                    {
                                        $join->on('vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'cars.id') 
                                             ->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', '1')
                                             ->where('cars.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
                                    })

                                    ->get();
```

And this works too:

```
$result = DB::table('vehicles')->join('motorcycles', function($join2) use($term)
                                    {
                                        $join2->on('vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'motorcycles.id')
                                             ->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', '2')
                                             ->where('motorcycles.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
                                   })
                                   ->get();
```

Each of those queries gives me a different results as expected, however, 2 joins in a row gives me nothing.

EDIT:

result of this:

```
$result = DB::table('vehicles')
    ->join('cars', 'vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'cars.id')
    ->join('motorcycles', 'vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'motorcycles.id')
    ->where('cars.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->orWhere('motorcycles.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->get();
```

is this:

```
    [query] => 
select vehicles.vehicle_type as vehicle_type, vehicles.vehicle_id as vehicle_id                                                                              

from `vehicles` inner join `cars` on `vehicles`.`vehicle_id` = `cars`.`id` and `vehicles`.`vehicle_type` = ? 

inner join `motorcycles` on `vehicles`.`vehicle_id` = `motorcycles`.`id` and `vehicles`.`vehicle_type` = ? where `cars`.`title` LIKE ? or `motorcycles`.`title` LIKE ?
    [bindings] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => %test%
        [3] => %test%
    )
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but what happens if you take out ```->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', '1')``` and ```->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', '2')```?

Comment: Can you add some sample data for the case "when I have a car and a motorcycle that have the same name and the $term contains part of it"?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have added table 1 example, to the OP, basically, the vehicle_id could be the same twice - once as a car (vehicle_type=1)  and the second as motorcycle (vehicle_type=2) .

Comment: @CUGreen I have thrown it out, but nothing changed. Still the same behavior, when I use only one join (doesn't matter which) it works. And each of those joints grabs different things as expected. But they don't work in tandem. Any idea what could be the problem? I have updated my question by the way, if it helps.

Comment: Shouldn't the ids in `cars` and `motorcycles` be 546 etc.?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, they are my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but here is a possible solution:

```
$result = DB::table('vehicles')
    ->join('cars', 'vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'cars.id')
    ->join('motorcycles', 'vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'motorcycles.id')
    ->where('cars.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->orWhere('motorcycles.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->get();
```

This should result in a sql statement as follows:

```
select * from `vehicles` 
inner join `cars` on `vehicles`.`vehicle_id` = `cars`.`id` 
inner join `motorcycles` on `vehicles`.`vehicle_id` = `motorcycles`.`id` 
where `cars`.`title` LIKE %term% 
or `motorcycles`.`title` LIKE %term%
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tired this as well, but nothing is in the result. It seems like the 2 joins in a row are the problem. If I use only one, doesn't matter which I get results. Two in a row nothing shows up.

Comment: what is the ```dd(DB::getQueryLog());```?

Comment: Hmm, again. only one join works. not both at the same time. ;(

Comment: You still have vehicles'.'vehicle_type' = ? I have taken that out of the code I provided so it should not appear in your sql statement

Comment: I tried different combinations. I have thrown out vehicle type completely, however the result is still empty when I use both joins. Btw, if I throw out the type the results are not good, that condition is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = DB::table('vehicles')
    ->leftJoin('cars', function($join) {
        $join->on('vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'cars.id')
            ->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', 1);
    })->leftJoin('motorcycles', function($join) {
        $join->on('vehicles.vehicle_id', '=', 'motorcycles.id')
            ->where('vehicles.vehicle_type', '=', 2);
    })
    ->where('cars.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->orWhere('motorcycles.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')
    ->get();
```